# How to select extra columns while using group by clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains data in this format.

```
productid     filterName         boolfilter            numericfilter
   1               X                 1                      NULL    
   1               Y                NULL                    99inch 
   1               Z                 0                      NULL
   2               Y                NULL                    55kg
   2               Y                NULL                    45kg
   3               K                NULL                    20
   3               M                NULL                    35
   3               N                NULL                    25
   4               X                 1                      NULL
   4               K                 1                      NULL
```

I need data in this format.
`Need products where only numeric filters are setup but no boolean filters`

```
productid    filterName       numericfilter
   2          Y                 55kg
   2          Y                 45kg
   3          K                 20
   3          M                 35
   3          N                 25
```

I have written this query,

```
 SELCT  productid
 FROM   tbl_filters
 GROUP BY    productid
 HAVING SUM(CAST(boolfilter AS INT)) IS NULL
```

I am getting prouctid 2 and 3, but i need the extra columns also as i have mentioned.
When i am using multiple columns in groupby clause i am not getting the required output.

Comment: Don't you have `1  Y   99inch` as first row in your required result.

Comment: @RagingBull: As i mentioned `I need only those products where only numeric filter is setup but for the productid 1 both numeric and boolean filter is present,so i do not need that.`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t.productid, t.filterName, t.numericfilter
FROM Table_Name t
WHERE t.numericfilter IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM TABLE_NAME 
                WHERE t.productid = productid
                AND boolfilter IS NOT NULL)
```

### [`Working SQL FIDDLE`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e34c8/4)

```
    | PRODUCTID | FILTERNAME | NUMERICFILTER |
    |-----------|------------|---------------|
    |         2 |          Y |          55kg |
    |         2 |          Y |          45kg |
    |         3 |          K |            20 |
    |         3 |          M |            35 |
    |         3 |          N |            25 |
```

Comment: +1 . . . This will probably perform better than my version, especially with an index on `table_name(productid, boolfilter)`.  If performance is an issue, though, it is always worth checking in your environment.

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions instead:

```
 SELECT productid, filterName, numericfilter
 FROM (SELECT f.*,
              MAX(boolfilter) OVER (PARTITION BY productid) as maxbf
       FROM tbl_filters f
      ) f
 WHERE maxbf is null;
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e34c8/3).

This calculates the maximum of `boolfilter` for each `productid`.  If it is always `NULL`, then the result is `NULL`.  Note that you don't need a `cast()` for this.

Comment: (+1) BTW, took the privilege to add the fiddle example.

Comment: Based on the prose of the question, this looks to be overengineered.

Comment: @DanBracuk: No... No... No...[**your result**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e34c8/8) won't meet OP's requirement.

Comment: @RagingBull sorry for stealing your Sql Fiddle :)

Comment: @M.Ali: No problem, my friend.

Comment: @GordonLioff sir not trying to criticism but strictly for educational purpose I have tried execution plans for both mine and your's solution and this is what they look like. [`Execution Plans`](http://postimg.org/image/yyjkq2ru9/), Do you recommend your suggested solution will work better in a certain schema?

Comment: @M.Ali . . . It is quite possible that yours will work faster, particularly with an index on `productid, boolfilter`.  It is worth the OP checking out, but my vote would be on the `not exists` method.  (Note:  the same index would probably be used for the window clause as well.) (Second note:  be careful about looking at execution plans on small amounts of data and generalizing to large amounts.)

Comment: very well said sir thank you for your feedback :) and +1 for teaching me something :)